# codeigniter passing some id to display a comment count for a pasticular post

Tags: php, codeigniter, parameter-passing

i am building a simple blog posting and commenting following the [codeigniter blog tutorial](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/) instruction. Now i am trying to implement a facebook-wall-comment like on one page using jquery ajax, i have manage to do the wall post, and the comment post on each wall, also grouping the comments into its corresponding post, but i am having problem displaying the comment count for each wall, i am thinking like doing something like this

Model:

```
function count_for_post($post_id){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT( id ) FROM comments WHERE post_id = ".$post_id);
    return $query; 
}
```

Controller:

```
function comments(){
    $data['comment_query'] = $this->commentmodel->count_for_post($post_id);
    $this->load->view('content/post/comment_view', $data);
}
```

how should i pass this `$post_id` parameters from  my view (all i can think of for now)

since my post controller is this:

```
function index(){
    $data['post_query'] = $this->postmodel->get_desc();
    $this->load->view('content/postview', $data);
}
```

and the only way i can fetch the particular id for each post is  by looping the `$post_query` in my view.

i want to display something like

```
contents of Post 1
    contents of comment regarding post1
    contents of comment regarding post1
    contents of comment regarding post1

    view all count($this->commentmodel->count_for_post($post_id))

contents of Post 2
    contents of comment regarding post2
    contents of comment regarding post2
    contents of comment regarding post2

    view all count($this->commentmodel->count_for_post($post_id2))

contents of Post 3
    contents of comment regarding post3
    contents of comment regarding post3
    contents of comment regarding post3

    view all count($this->commentmodel->count_for_post($post_id3))
```

please help me on implementing the "best practice" way to do this, which is: what should i write on my model, my controller and my view.

best regards

Comment: When doing a count don't do `return count($query->result_array());`. Instead to a MySQL count

Comment: oh thanks john, i'll revise that

Comment: i think it's a question of preference - i for one do not think that you should query your DB when you can do the calculation in php, it's faster and less resource consuming. i would have simply counted the amount of posts in the view from the `$data` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using `count()` to count the comments! Just count the returned rows using `num_rows()` which was created for that purpose.

eg:

```
<?php 
    $count_comments = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = ".$post_row['id']);
    echo $count_comments->num_rows();
?>
```

Comment: is it ok for me to write this inside my view ??

Comment: no, the view is only for presentation, you must create a function (eg: commentcount) and instead of echo'ing the count just return it